# http::geturl command possibly leaking memory despite token cleanup

Tags: tcl

I'm having an issue where The Tcl interpreter's memory usage goes up by 4KB when I send out an http::getURL request.  Here's what I do:

- Make the request in a procedure called `sendCommand` with a separate callback procedure.
- Process the returned token in the callback.
- Clean up the token at the end of `sendCommand`.

The cleanup command appears to be working fine (I checked by attempting to access the token's state array after the token was cleaned and as expected, it did not exist).
I did notice that the global references to the token (`::http::1`, `::http::2`, etc.) keep incrementing for every request even if they're cleaned up.  I thought this was odd, but seems to just be how the http package works.

Below is the `sendCommand` procedure and one of the callback procedures, `subscribeDevice`.  The code is running in a Linux environment (Angstrom).

```
#====================================================================================================
# sendCommand
#
#   Desc:   Sends a command to an HTTP server.
#   Param:  type        -   The type of HTTP request being made (GET, POST, PUT, no_options)
#           url         -   The host url.
#           query       -   The "payload" (For POST and PUT types only)
#           callback    -   The procedure to call upon receiving the http response of the request.
#====================================================================================================
proc sendCommand {type url query {callbackProc "::callback::default"}} {
    set token -1
    switch -nocase $type {
        "GET"   {
                    if {$callbackProc == "::callback::getLatestEventID" || $callbackProc ==  "::callback::getEvents"} {
                        set token [::http::geturl $url -headers [list Authorization "Bearer $::auth::accessTokenCC"] -handler $callbackProc -timeout 8000] 
                    } elseif {$callbackProc == "::callback::negotiateConnection"} {
                        set token [::http::geturl $url -headers [list Authorization "Bearer $::auth::accessToken"] -handler $callbackProc -timeout 15000]
                    } else {
                        set token [::http::geturl $url -headers [list Authorization "Bearer $::auth::accessToken" Cookie $::cookie] -handler $callbackProc -timeout 8000] 
                    }
                }
        "POST"  { 
                    if {$callbackProc == "::callback::getChannelID"} {
                        set token [::http::geturl $url -headers [list Authorization "Bearer $::auth::accessToken" Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded Cookie $::cookie] -query $query -handler $callbackProc -timeout 8000]
                    } else {
                        set token [::http::geturl $url -headers [list Authorization "Basic $::auth::BASIC_AUTH"] -query $query -handler $callbackProc -timeout 8000]
                        if {$callbackProc == "::callback::refreshTokens"} {
                            if { [::http::ncode $token] != 200} {
                                clearTimer "refreshTokensTID"
                                set ::refreshTokensTID [setTimer 10000]
                            }
                        }   
                    }

                }
        "PUT"   { 
                    set token [::http::geturl $url -headers [list Authorization "Bearer $::auth::accessToken" Content-Type application/json Cookie $::cookie] -query $query -method $type -handler $callbackProc -timeout 8000]
                }
    }
    LOG "Token: $token"
    LOG "Token Status:  [::http::status $token]"
    LOG "Token NCode:   [::http::ncode $token]"
    if {$token != -1} {
        ::http::cleanup $token
    }
}

#====================================================================================================
# subscribeDevice
#
#   Desc:   Callback for ::signalR::subscribeDevice
#   Param:  socket  - The socket to read the HTTP data from (required by -handler option of ::http::geturl)
#           token   - The returned data (required by -handler option of ::http::geturl)
#   Return: n/a
#====================================================================================================
proc subscribeDevice {socket token} {
    LOG "Token: $token"
    set data [read $socket]
    LOG "data = $data"
}
```

Comment: The token ids are generated by an internal increment of a hidden variable. So long as you `http::cleanup` the token, there shouldn't be any leaks. Leaks would be Bad. It's not clear from what you've posted what is leaking though…

Comment: You're using `-handler` in your http::geturl calls rather than `-command`.  This strikes me as odd, since you end up not using the event loop to invoke your callbacks and you may end up with partial responses.  However I don't know your code so this may be correct in your usage.